# error in looping over files, -fs- command

Tags: loops, foreach, split, stata

I'm trying to split some datasets in two parts, running a loop over files like this:

```
 cd C:\Users\Macrina\Documents\exports
 qui fs *
 foreach f in `r(files)' {
    use `r(files)'
        keep id adv*
        save adv_spa*.dta
        clear
    use `r(files)'
        drop adv*
        save fin_spa*.dta
 }
```

I don't know whether what is inside the loop is correctly written but the point is that I get the error:

```
invalid '"e2.dta'
```

where e2.dta is the second file in the folder. Does this message refer to the loop or maybe what is inside the loop? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Is `adv_spa*.dta` allowed as a filename by your OS? I expect that to be illegal given the scope for referring to files with wildcard notation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not working as I wanted and I get an error message:    file advisors_spain*.dta could not be opened    . I try renaming them.

Answer (score 1):

You want lines like

```
use "`f'"
```

not

```
use `r(files)'
```

given that `fs` (installed from SSC, as you should explain) returns `r(files)` as a list of ***all the files*** whereas you want to `use` ***each one in turn*** (not all at once).

The error message was informative: `use` is puzzled by the second filename it sees (as only one filename makes sense). The other filenames are ignored: `use` fails as soon as something is evidently wrong.

Incidentally, note that putting `""` around filenames remains essential if any includes spaces.